Finding RDS client host by IP across VPC peer
I've inherited management of an AWS account (an entire Org, actually) an inside is an RDS instance. I've enabled enhanced monitoring and can observe that something is periodically running a query

I can also see it's something from within the the VPC since it's a 10.x.x.x address. I need to find out what compute resource is invoking this query.
First I tried describe-instances which yielded nothing.

So then I checked the VPC subnets and see that an enclosing range is there: 10.8.0.0/20

So then I looked at peering connections and sure enough, there it is

But what I don't know how to do at this point is figure out which resource in the requesting account's range of 172.31.0.0/16 is being mapped/peered as 10.8.8.112. Any guidance?

Can you turn on query logging inside the database? That might record the IP address. Alternately you can use AWS VPC Flow Logs - they're not fun to read, but they work.
